# Count unique colors of RGB Image using OpenCV/EmguCV

Tags: opencv, colors, histogram, emgucv

How can i count unique colors of image ROI.
I try to use Histogram but i don't know how to handle Bin values. Here is my code so far using EMguCV:

```
image.ROI= new Rectangle(10,10,300,500);
Image<Gray, Byte>[] gray = image.Split(); 
DenseHistogram hist = new DenseHistogram(256, new RangeF(0f, 256f));
hist.Calculate(new Image<Gray, byte>[] { gray[0] }, false, null);
float[] r = hist.GetBinValues();
hist.Calculate(new Image<Gray, byte>[] { gray[1] }, false, null);
float[] g = hist.GetBinValues();
hist.Calculate(new Image<Gray, byte>[] { gray[2] }, false, null);
float[] b = hist.GetBinValues();
```

How can calculate r,g,b values to get the number of used colors?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you are going to be happy for this. but the brute force method is

```
 Image<Bgr, byte> test = new Image<Bgr, byte>(@"C:\Lena.jpeg");
        List<Bgr> thePixelList = new List<Bgr>();
        for (int j = 0; j < test.Cols; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < test.Rows; i++)
            {                  
                thePixelList.Add(test[i, j]);

            }
        }


        int theCount = thePixelList.Distinct().Count();
```

Comment: thank you for suggestion i thought about it too but this approach takes too much time.

Comment: As I read your question, this is a “select distinct” problem. In addition, as I remember is “select distinct” an NP-hardproblem. Therefore, you will two need steps. - Copy data to another array(unless you want to do you sorting in place) - Use the NP-Hard Distinct. I don’t see how you will get around this.

Comment: Yeah, the loop above looks very NP-Hard.